# Spring Webflux ErrorHandling - @RestControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler or DefaultErrorAttributes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, error-handling, spring-webflux

In **Spring Webflux** what is the prefered way of Exception Handling?

@RestControllerAdvice comes from Spring MVC whereas DefaultErrorAttributes comes from Spring Webflux.

However, in Spring Webflux someone could use @RestControllerAdvice. What would be the advantages/disadvantages?

**@RestControllerAdvice**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Mono<Map<String, Object>> exceptions(Throwable e)
    {
        return Mono.just(Map.of("message", "bad"));
    }
}
```

**Extend DefaultErrorAttributes**

```
@Component
public class ErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace)
    {
        var ex = getError(request);

        var attributes = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        attributes.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        attributes.put("message", "bad");

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

I want to stay in the reactive world, so I tend more towards DefaultErrorAttributes (which plays well with DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler in Webflux). However, in @RestControllerAdvice I could also use Mono.just(...).

Comment: I note that it's "been a while" and there's no response. Is this because it is "a preference thing"? I am also fairly new to Webflux, and it would be good to hear from those who've been doing this longer (i.e., I'm fairly certain there's a reason that extending *DefaultErrorAttributes* is "an added option" in Webflux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same. Like WebMvc.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(AnyException.class)
    public Mono<EntityResponse<YourModel>> example(AnyException exception) {
        return EntityResponse.fromObject(new YourModel()).status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The method is called, but it looks like the `Mono<EntityResponse>` is never subscribed to, so the return code is always 200 with a default body.

Comment: Double-check your exception or parent of them. I guess, in your case didn't match. So, If I have `class A extends B` and `class B extends RuntimeException` and I throw `A`. `A`, `B` and `RuntimeException` can catch exception.
Your problem is hard for me because I don't know how you implemented your program.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Webflux in case functional routes declaration, you can also implement your own ExceptionHandler instead of [DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler.html):

```
    class SystemErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable throwable) {
        return super.handle(exchange, throwable)
                    // debug, process
                    .contextWrite(...);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        // for all routs
        return route(all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> error = getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.of());
        Throwable t = this.getError(request);
        // map exception on response
        return ServerResponse.status(status).body(...);
    }
}
```

Then use your implementation of AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler in the spring configuration with @AutoConfigureBefore(WebFluxAutoConfiguration.class)